# sed multiline remove before pattern

Tags: unix, awk, sed, multiline

Hi I have a big log file for which I am trying to get xml data passed into It.

I have a big log file which ressembles this :

```
2016/01/01   bladh bqskjdqskldjqsdlqskdjqlskdj dazihzmkldjkdjqslkjd
2016/01/01:  qsdhqsdlkqsmdjqsldjqslkdjqlskdjqslkdjqslkdjqskdjqsd
2016/01/01: qsjdqmlskdmlqskdmcxxxx [qskjd][qsdjqslkdj] Payload    :[<LOG><a>a</a>
<b>b</b>
<c>c</c>
<id>XXXXX</id>
<d>d</d>
</LOG>]]

2016/01/01   bladh bqskjdqskldjqsdlqskdjqlskdj dazihzmkldjkdjqslkjd
2016/01/01:  qsdhqsdlkqsmdjqsldjqslkdjqlskdjqslkdjqslkdjqskdjqsd
2016/01/01: qsjdqmlskdmlqskdmcxxxx [qskjd][qsdjqslkdj] Payload :[<LOG>    <a>a</a>
<b>b</b>
<c>c</c>
<id>YYYYY</id>
<d>d</d>
</LOG>]]
qskdmqlskdqlsdqlskdqlsdk
qsdlkqsdlkqsdmlkqsdlk
```

For now I am using

```
  sed -n '/<START/{:start /\/END/!{N;b start};/XXXXX/p}' logFile
```

and I am getting this

```
    2016/01/01: qsjdqmlskdmlqskdmcxxxx [qskjd][qsdjqslkdj] Payload    :[<LOG><a>a</a>
<b>b</b>
<c>c</c>
<id>XXXXX</id>
<d>d</d>
</LOG>]]
```

I would like to retrieve the whole XML and get :

```
<LOG>    
   <a>a</a>
   <b>b</b>
   <c>c</c>
   <id>XXXX</id>
   <d>d</d>
</LOG>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: try `grep -oPz '(?s)<LOG>.*?</LOG>' logFile | tr '\0' '\n'` to retrieve all `<LOG>...</LOG>`

Comment: How about `sed '/^</!d'`?

Comment: I suppose my grep is outdated ??
      grep: The -P and -z options cannot be combined

Comment: check your man page, might be `-Z` instead of `-z`

Answer (score 1):

Solution in [TXR](http://nongnu.org/txr):

```
@(repeat)
@  (skip)Payload :[<@tag>@preamble
@  (collect)
@middle
@  (last)
</@tag>]]
@  (end)
@  (output)
<@tag>
  @(trim-str preamble)
@    (repeat)
  @middle
@    (end)
</@tag>
@  (end)
@(end)
```

Run:

```
$ txr extract.txr data
<LOG>
  <a>a</a>
  <b>b</b>
  <c>c</c>
  <id>XXXXX</id>
  <d>d</d>
</LOG>
<LOG>
  <a>a</a>
  <b>b</b>
  <c>c</c>
  <id>YYYYY</id>
  <d>d</d>
</LOG>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
sed -n '/<LOG/{:a;/<\/LOG/!{N;ba};s/.*\(<LOG>\)\(.*XXXXX.*<\/LOG>\).*/\1\n\2/p}' logFile
```

It should do the job but keep in mind that sed is not the right tool for parsing xml. When you'll have to parse valid xml files, you should consider using [xmlstarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/) or [xmllint](http://xmlsoft.org/xmllint.html).

Comment: Hi Thanks a lot, This seems to work, but can you please explain.. I do not want to just copy and paste..

Also, how do I filter my XXXX only request.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -nr '/<LOG>/,/<\/LOG>/{s/.*(<LOG>)\s*/\1\n/;s/(<\/LOG>).*/\1/;p}' file
```

Use seds grep-like option to inhibit printing unless explicitly required and utilise the range feature `/.../,/.../`, top and tailing the string produced.